# Change java version (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I have 2 java versions on my computer:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The 1.6.0 is set to default. How can I make my java programs to run 1.7?

Tried to add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home
```

to my *.zshrc* file. But this seems to only change the path for my terminals `java` command.

Also tried to change the HOME symlink like this:

```
cd /Library/Java
mv Home Home-1.6
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/ Home
```

This had no effect at all.

Also tried java changer software:
http://www.guigarage.com/2013/02/change-java-version-on-mac-os/
But no effect.

Any idea how to start java programs like .app and .jar files with the 1.7 version by just clicking on them?

Comment: what does the terminal say if you type java -version?

Comment: closed as off topic?  "...unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." The jdk is almost exclusively used for programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe OS X (at least 10.8) uses the following paths:

- JRE: `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current`
- JDK: `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK`

Those are symlinks, which you can update to point to your 1.7 installation.

You can verify this fairly easily:

a) run `which java` to check which java executable is being executed. In theory, that should be `/usr/bin/java`.

b) run `ls -la` on your java executable, which should tell you where it points (`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`
 on my machine).

I think this should sort your `.jar` execution issue. If your Java application is wrapped in a `.app`, I believe it's a bit more complex: if memory serves, the version of java used will depend on the `JavaApplicationStub` being used by the `.app`.

Comment: I think that last part is the actual answer to the problem: "version of java used will depend on the JavaApplicationStub being used by the .app.". Guess it´s me doing wrong when using Jar Bundle(no 1.7 support....)

Comment: In that case, [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Apr/msg00115.html) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ edit ~/.profile

#Java 1.8
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}


$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
```

here are the steps:

http://ukitech.blogspot.com/2014/04/switching-version-of-java-on-mac.html

Comment: Try to add some of the detailed steps from the link...future users may not have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add [into your profile](http://trickortip.com/312/andres-felipe-diaz-2/where-is-the-profile-file-in-mac-os-x-lion-mac-terminal-trick.html/) both on Mac or Linux. Just create if doesn't exist ~/.profile file and there this line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home
```

This should work .zshrc as well as .bash_profile are loaded only when terminal window is openned and [profile when your graphical environment starts up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal).